# How to come back to first activity from third activity?

Tags: android

I have three activities A,B & C.Now the Task i have this form A,B and C,in default android  "standard"mode The activities navigation takes place like this A->B->C->B->A.Now What I want here is when I went to Activity C from B,when i backPressed In activity I went to previous Activity i.e.,B But i want to come back to A from C.How to achieve this could anyone tell about this??

,I want to do through intent flags or if possible want to apply launchmodes for the activities,But i am confused which launch mode should i use to achieve this ?-could any one please help me in this

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just launch a new intent and clear the activities in the stack.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
 intent.addFlags(IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But this will called oncreate() of Activity A ,any idea to avoid it ?

Comment: Use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` to avoid reload

Answer (score 1):

Use `finish()` method when you start Activity C.
i.e.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `finish()` the Activity B when you launch Activity C. So your stack would just be A->C.
Use `ActivityB.finish()` method before starting the Activity C. Other method could be to override the back button key pressed.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //do your process here
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: @ALL thank u very much for your responses,I want to do through intent flags or if possible want to apply launchmodes for the activities,But i am confused which launch mode should i use to achieve this ?-could any one please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

Use `Fragments`. Fragments are added to containers and are replaced by others when you like. The replaced Fragment can be added to the stack, or not. That you can decide for yourself.
In this case the flow would be like:

- MainActivity adds a Fragment A to a container.
- Button is pressed
- Fragment A is replaced by Fragment B. Fragment A is being added to
  the stack with `.addToBackStack(..)`
- Fragment B is shown
- Button is pressed
- Fragment B is replaced by Fragment C. Fragment B is not being added to the stack.
- Fragment C is shown
- Back is pressed
- Fragment A is shown

**Update**

You can start by reading the [documention](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) Android provided.

A simple example to get you started and explain the basics. I am using the Android support library v4 for fragment to support older versions than HoneyComb:

**main_activiy - XML**

```
<LinearLayout>
   <FrameLayout id:content_container/>
<LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activiy ); 
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.content_container, new FragmentA());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment A** (analog you can create Fragment B and C)

```
public class Fragment A extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false); 
        return view;
    }
}
```

You can implement logic inside your `Fragment` and catch for example a click-event. This is how you can switch between fragments from a OnClickListener:

```
private class mClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_container, new FragmentB);
            transaction.addToBackStack(...); // Remove this when you don't want it to be stacked
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Martijn Van Mierloo Thank u ..could u give me any link for fragments

Answer (score 0):

You could override the onBackPressed method in your activity to start your A activity instead of back tracing your history tree.

Answer (score 0):

you should call finish(); in B activity when you move to

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution which won't require :
   1- To override onBackPressed() in Activity C 
   2- To call  startActivity(A) from C and hence no need to create extra intent.
   3- No need to call finish() in Activity B.

Just need to add intent flag in Activity A where you are starting B as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);// Only need this line in A.java
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Go back to **A** Activity class from **C** without reload the first activity class then try the below code

And this will remove the in-between activities from backstack as well.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```