# How remove last activity from the stack?

Tags: android

I have 3 activitys (A, B, C), the flow is:

```
A -> B -> C
```

when i click to back, the flow is:

```
C -> B -> A
```

but i want this:

```
C -> A
```

not

```
C -> B -> A
```

how?

Comment: When you leave B and start C just call `finish()` in B

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to come back to first activity from third activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626876/how-to-come-back-to-first-activity-from-third-activity)

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

---

If you know which activity you don't want to remove from the stack, all you have to do is call `finish()` after your call `startActivity(intent)` to the next activity, so this activity will be excluded from the flow, see the example below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

---

If the decision will happen based on an interaction with the user, you can call `startActivityForResult()` to start the next activity, and when the activity ends, you have to return a RESULT value.

Here's a good documentation about how to use `startActivityForResult()`:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html