# How to go back to a previous Activity in activity stack which contains fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are 3 activities :

Main Activity (Contains 3 fragments : a. Profile Fragment , b. Order Fragment, Item Fragment)
Order Summary Activity
Payment Screen

The flow : Main Activity(Profile Fragment) -> Main Activity(Item Fragment) -> Order Summary Activity -> Payment Screen -> Main Activity(Order Fragment)

So basically I wanted to know how can I go from Payment Screen to Main Activity(Order Fragment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626876/how-to-come-back-to-first-activity-from-third-activity

Answer (score 0):

Just launch a new intent and clear the activities in the stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
 intent.addFlags(IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
 startActivity(intent);
```

Original answer Source from [how-to-come-back-to-first-activity-from-third-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626876/how-to-come-back-to-first-activity-from-third-activity)